# I have a listbox and I would like to store all the values in an array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel-2010

When I click on the generate Button, then it should save all values from the listbox2 to an array.
Then I would like to generate new Excel Documents with the array values.

This is my code:

```
   Dim i As Integer

   Private Sub btn_CopyValue_Click()

   For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1

     If ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then ListBox2.AddItem ListBox1.List(i)

     Next i

     End Sub


Private Sub GenerateExcelSheets_Click()
    Dim Size As Integer

    Size = Me.ListBox2.ListCount - 1

    ReDim ListBoxContents(0 To Size) As String

    Dim i As Integer

   For i = 0 To Size
      ListBoxContents(i) = Me.ListBox2.ItemData(i)

    Next i

    For i = 0 To Size
      MsgBox ListBoxContents(i)
    Next i
   End Sub
```

I don't know why it is nor working...

Answer (score 0):

You are putting `ItemData(i)` into the array, as you never assign to an items `ItemData` you presumably mean to load the items text, change to:

```
ListBoxContents(i) = Me.ListBox2.List(i)
```